# Create a countdown timer (that accounts for SetInterval/Timeout Google Chrome tab "error")

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timer, settimeout

I created a countdown timer in Javascript; it was successful, expect not complete. In fact, mathematically, it is correct, but Google Chrome's browser settings "pause" (for lack of a better term) SetInterval/Timeout, which means that if a user of my countdown program switches between tabs on their browser, then the execution of the function will not occur exactly at the set time limit.

I need help implementing this basic time logic from W3Schools: 
http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_timing_clock

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

and this attempt to account for the browser SetInterval/Timeout interference: http://jsfiddle.net/7f6DX/31/

```
var div = $('div');
var a = 0;
var delay = (1000 / 30);
var now, before = new Date();


setInterval(function() {
    now = new Date();
    var elapsedTime = (now.getTime() - before.getTime());
    if(elapsedTime > delay)
        //Recover the motion lost while inactive.
        a += Math.floor(elapsedTime/delay);
    else
        a++;
    div.css("right", a);
    before = new Date();    
}, delay);
```

Thanks for any help that you can provide.

Comment: I'm confused, are you trying to build a clock, a countdown timer, or an animation?

Comment: Thanks for your reply; I am trying to build an alarm clock countdown timer that will go off after 10 minutes. The problem is that when I switch between tabs in the browser the timer goes off at 13 or 14 minutes due to the delay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use *real-world time* to update your timer instead of relying on the accuracy of `setInterval`.

The w3schools example you gave does exactly this; every 500ms it grabs the current time, formats it, and updates the display. When the tab is inactive, this update may occur less frequently than 500ms (Chrome can slow it down to once every 1-2s), but nevertheless, when the update *does* occur, you will display correct information.

```js
// countdown for 1 minute
countdown(60);

function countdown(seconds) {
  // current timestamp.
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  // target timestamp; we will compute the remaining time
  // relative to this date.
  var target = new Date(now + seconds * 1000);
  // update frequency; note, this is flexible, and when the tab is
  // inactive, there are no guarantees that the countdown will update
  // at this frequency.
  var update = 500;
  
  var int = setInterval(function () {
    // current timestamp
    var now = new Date();
    // remaining time, in seconds
    var remaining = (target - now) / 1000;
    
    // if done, alert
    if (remaining < 0) {
      clearInterval(int);
      return;
    }
    
    // format
    var minutes = ~~(remaining / 60);
    var seconds = ~~(remaining % 60);
    
    // display
    document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML
      = format(minutes) + ":" + format(seconds);
  }, update);
}

function format(num) {
  return num < 10 ? "0" + num : num;
}
```

```html
<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Run this snippet and switch around to different tabs. Your countdown will be off by a maximum of 500ms (the update frequency).

---

For what it's worth, a similar idea can be applied to animations.

When designing an animation, you should have a formula for the position *x* as a function of time *t*. Your *rendering clock* (whether it is `setInterval`, `setTimeout`, or `requestAnimationFrame`) is not necessarily reliable, but your *physics clock* (real-world time) is. You should decouple the two.

Every time you need to render a frame, consult the physics clock for the time *t*, calculate the position *x*, and render that position. [This](http://acko.net/blog/animate-your-way-to-glory/) is a really great blog post which goes into great detail on animations and physics, from which I borrowed the above idea.

Comment: This has been incredibly helpful Igor Raush, thank you for your thorough answer and for the blog post resource.

Comment: @Trevor not a problem! If this answer is sufficient for you, please accept it.